# How do you clean up resources at the end of a pytest session?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have a suite of selenium end to end tests. I instantiate one `webdriver.ChromeDriver` instance that I pass as a fixture to every test in the suite.

```
'''python3
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver(request):
    return d(request)
'''
```

After the last test runs I want to close the webdriver instance with `driver.quit()`.

I can accomplish this with a fixture

```
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def close_after_test_suite(driver, requests):
    if requests:
        driver.quit()
```

However this only runs if tests do not fail during the suite. If every test passes, the browser will close. If a single test fails then the browser will be left open.

How can I use pytest to close my browser at the end of the test suite regardless of whether or not tests fail?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run some code on teardown, use `yield` instead of `return`, for example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver(request):
    driver = d(request)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

However, the `selenium.webdriver.WebDriver` classes implement the context manager magic methods, so you can also use the `with` statement:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver(request):
    with d(request) as driver:
        yield driver
```

Another (although pretty old, but still working) option is using the [`request.addfinalizer`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.addfinalizer) option:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver(request):
    driver = d(request)

    def f():
        driver.quit()

    request.addfinalizer(f)
    return driver
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much for getting back tome so quickly!

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answers your question, you can upvote and accept it, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)